# Numpy average function rounding off error

Tags: python, numpy, average

I find this very weird.  Can someone tell me whats going on here?

```
>>>a = [1,0,1]
>>>np.mean(a)
   0.66666666666666663
>>>2.0/3
   0.6666666666666666
```

What's up with the 3 in the end of the output of `np.mean(a)`? Why isn't it a 6 like the line below it or a 7(when rounding off)?

Comment: Why the downvotes? At least explain. This seams totally reasonable...unless you don't actually read the question...

Comment: @Brian This question has been answered many, many times on this forum.

Comment: @Ophion so downvote, comment that it's a dupe, and link to one. Why should people just 'hit and run' downvote a new user when the dupes don't show up in a search or in the related list?

Comment: @Brain You would have to ask them, but it is a question that is easily answer by google which is essentially check #1 on the SO question [checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: @Ophion: this is not the standard `OMG, 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.30000004!!` you see three times per day, this seems like a valid question that surprised me as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just a case of a different string representation of two different types:

```
In [17]: a = [1, 0, 1]

In [18]: mean(a)
Out[18]: 0.66666666666666663

In [19]: type(mean(a))
Out[19]: numpy.float64

In [20]: 2.0 / 3
Out[20]: 0.6666666666666666

In [21]: type(2.0 / 3)
Out[21]: float

In [22]: mean(a).item()
Out[22]: 0.6666666666666666
```

They compare equal:

```
In [24]: mean(a) == 2.0 / 3
Out[24]: True

In [25]: mean(a).item() == 2.0 / 3
Out[25]: True
```

Now might be the time to read about [`numpy` scalars](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) and [`numpy` dtypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Comment: A python float should also be 64 bit, still a bit weird that numpy prints that differently.

Comment: @BasSwinckels Not sure I follow your argument. Are you saying that because they are both floating point types with a 64-bit representation that they should `repr` the same, even though they are distinct types in the type hierarchy?

Comment: I understand they are different types with different reprs, but both should wrap the same float64 value. It seems that in this case, no effort is done to make the repr show what type it really is, so I just find it slightly surprising that they do not use the same algorithm to create the string representation.

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this has been discussed on the NumPy ML. I don't really have time to look into it, but I would bet you'll find more information there.