# extra decimals in numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say I have one list of floats and a numpy array that I wish to zip:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> n1 = [0.9, 1.1]
>>> n2 = np.array([0.9,1.1])
>>> zip(n1,n2)
    [(0.9, 0.90000000000000002), (1.1, 1.1000000000000001)]
```

Why am I getting all those decimals? Is there a way to make the numpy floats behave like python floats?

EDIT:
It seems that calculations are also affected by the way numpy stores floats:

```
>>> nb1 = n2[1]+0.1
>>> nb1
    1.2000000000000002
>>> nb2 = nb1 - 1.2 #nb2 should be equal to 0
    2.2204460492503131e-16
>>> nb3 = np.asscalar(nb2)
>>> nb3
    2.2204460492503131e-16 #nb3 should be equal to 0
>>> type(nb3)
    float
```

Comment: That's just how floats are represented in numpy, Python I'd guess

Answer (score 2):

Both the python floats and the numpy arrays are probably 64-bit floating point numbers, but they are 'encapsulated' in different objects. The difference is probably due to different `repr` for python floats and numpy floats.

```
In [12]: n1[0]
Out[12]: 0.9

In [13]: n2[0]
Out[13]: 0.90000000000000002

In [14]: n1[0] == n2[0]
Out[14]: True

In [15]: type(n1[0])
Out[15]: float

In [16]: type(n2[0])
Out[16]: numpy.float64
```

The same problem probably triggered [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18622795/numpy-average-function-rounding-off-error). Personally, I consider this a bug in numpy.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I suppose that means there's no way I can make numpy floats behave like python floats then?

Comment: They should behave the same in calculations, it is just a printing issue,which can be circumvented by explicitly converting to string. Make sure you understand [floating point issues](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). Also note that zip returns a list of tuples, it is more natural in this case to put everything in a  Nx2 array, which would convert the pyy

Comment: Damn comment edit timeout. ...., which would convert the python floats to numpy floats.

Comment: @Bas You can always copy, delete, paste as new comment. Kind of annoying for marked down links though :P

Comment: @Bas Swinckels: It seems that calculations are also affected. I edited my answer with an example.

Comment: No they are not. Your original question was about the difference in printing between python and numpy floats, which is a valid question. The calculation issue you mention now is caused by standard floating point inaccuracies, which are explained in the link I gave in a previous comment. This issue is the same for python and numpy: `((n2[1] + 0.1) - 1.2) == ((n1[1] + 0.1) - 1.2)` gives `True`. This gets asked 3 times per day.